# Получение аргумента командной строки

Tags: c, строки

Из командной строки нужно получить два агрумента: значение типа `int` и текстовое сообщение, после - вывести оба аргумента. 
С числом все понятно, скажите пожалуйста, как быть со строкой?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SIZE_BUFF 255

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int t;
    char str[SIZE_BUFF];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Need exactly 2 args\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    t = atoi(argv[1]);
    fgets(str, 255, stdin);
    strtok(str, "\n");
    printf("first = %d\nsecond: %s\n", t, str);
}
```

Comment: Аргумент командной строки - он уже строка. Ничего делать не надо - берите и пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Need exactly 2 args\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("first = %d\nsecond: %s\n", atoi(argv[1]), argv[2]);
}
```

Получаем

```
G:\Tmp\Test>test.exe  150 "Text message"
first = 150
second: Text message

G:\Tmp\Test>
```